# Opengl es 2.0 draw bitmap overlay on video

Tags: java, android, bitmap, opengl-es-2.0, video-processing

I am trying to draw a bitmap as an overlay on every frame of the video. I found an example on how to decode and encode a video and it is working. This example has a TextureRenderer class with a `drawFrame` function that I need to modify in order to add the bitmap. I am newbie to opengl but I learnt that I need to create a texture with the bitmap and bind it. I tried that in the following code but it is throwing an exception.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
// from: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/lollipop-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/TextureRender.java
// blob: 4125dcfcfed6ed7fddba5b71d657dec0d433da6a
// modified: removed unused method bodies
// modified: use GL_LINEAR for GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER to improve quality.

package com.example.name.videoeditortest;
/**
 * Code for rendering a texture onto a surface using OpenGL ES 2.0.
 */

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.opengl.GLES11Ext;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

/**
 * Code for rendering a texture onto a surface using OpenGL ES 2.0.
 */
class TextureRender {
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private static final String TAG = "TextureRender";
    private static final int FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0;
    private static final int TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3;
    private final float[] mTriangleVerticesData = {
            // X, Y, Z, U, V
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 0.f, 0.f,
            1.0f, -1.0f, 0, 1.f, 0.f,
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 0.f, 1.f,
            1.0f,  1.0f, 0, 1.f, 1.f,
    };
    private FloatBuffer mTriangleVertices;
    private static final String VERTEX_SHADER =
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
                    "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
                    "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                    "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                    "void main() {\n" +
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
                    "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
                    "}\n";
    private static final String FRAGMENT_SHADER =
            "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                    "precision mediump float;\n" +      // highp here doesn't seem to matter
                    "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                    "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                    "void main() {\n" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                    "}\n";
    private float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];
    private int mProgram;
    private int mTextureID = -12345;
    private int mTextureBitmapID = -12345;
    private int muMVPMatrixHandle;
    private int muSTMatrixHandle;
    private int maPositionHandle;
    private int maTextureHandle;
    public TextureRender() {
        mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                mTriangleVerticesData.length * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES)
                .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
    }
    public int getTextureId() {
        return mTextureID;
    }
    public void drawFrame(SurfaceTexture st) {
        checkGlError("onDrawFrame start");
        st.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix);
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);
        checkGlError("glUseProgram");
        //Bing textrues
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
        GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureBitmapID);

        mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle");
        mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET);
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices);
        checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle");
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle);
        checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle");
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0);
        GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
        checkGlError("glDrawArrays");
        GLES20.glFinish();
    }
    /**
     * Initializes GL state.  Call this after the EGL surface has been created and made current.
     */
    public void surfaceCreated() {
        mProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        if (mProgram == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed creating program");
        }
        maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition");
        checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition");
        if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition");
        }
        maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord");
        checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord");
        if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord");
        }
        muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix");
        if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix");
        }
        muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix");
        checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix");
        if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix");
        }
        int[] textures = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        mTextureID = textures[0];
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, mTextureID);
        checkGlError("glBindTexture mTextureID");
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        checkGlError("glTexParameter");

        mTextureBitmapID = loadBitmapTexture();
    }


    private int loadBitmapTexture()
    {
        final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);

        if (textureHandle[0] != 0)
        {
            // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);

            // Set filtering
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

            // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
            GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
        }

        if (textureHandle[0] == 0)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
        }

        return textureHandle[0];
    }

    /**
     * Replaces the fragment shader.
     */
    public void changeFragmentShader(String fragmentShader) {
        GLES20.glDeleteProgram(mProgram);
        mProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, fragmentShader);
        if (mProgram == 0) {
            throw new RuntimeException("failed creating program");
        }
    }
    private int loadShader(int shaderType, String source) {
        int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType);
        checkGlError("glCreateShader type=" + shaderType);
        GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source);
        GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);
        int[] compiled = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0);
        if (compiled[0] == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader " + shaderType + ":");
            Log.e(TAG, " " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader));
            GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader);
            shader = 0;
        }
        return shader;
    }
    private int createProgram(String vertexSource, String fragmentSource) {
        int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource);
        if (vertexShader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource);
        if (pixelShader == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        int program = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
        checkGlError("glCreateProgram");
        if (program == 0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not create program");
        }
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader);
        checkGlError("glAttachShader");
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(program);
        int[] linkStatus = new int[1];
        GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0);
        if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ");
            Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program));
            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program);
            program = 0;
        }
        return program;
    }
    public void checkGlError(String op) {
        int error;
        while ((error = GLES20.glGetError()) != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
            Log.e(TAG, op + ": glError " + error);
            throw new RuntimeException(op + ": glError " + error);
        }
    }

    public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        this.bitmap = bitmap;

    }
    /**
     * Saves the current frame to disk as a PNG image.  Frame starts from (0,0).
     * <p>
     * Useful for debugging.
     */
    public static void saveFrame(String filename, int width, int height) {
        // glReadPixels gives us a ByteBuffer filled with what is essentially big-endian RGBA
        // data (i.e. a byte of red, followed by a byte of green...).  We need an int[] filled
        // with native-order ARGB data to feed to Bitmap.
        //
        // If we implement this as a series of buf.get() calls, we can spend 2.5 seconds just
        // copying data around for a 720p frame.  It's better to do a bulk get() and then
        // rearrange the data in memory.  (For comparison, the PNG compress takes about 500ms
        // for a trivial frame.)
        //
        // So... we set the ByteBuffer to little-endian, which should turn the bulk IntBuffer
        // get() into a straight memcpy on most Android devices.  Our ints will hold ABGR data.
        // Swapping B and R gives us ARGB.  We need about 30ms for the bulk get(), and another
        // 270ms for the color swap.
        //
        // Making this even more interesting is the upside-down nature of GL, which means we
        // may want to flip the image vertically here.
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(width * height * 4);
        buf.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buf);
        buf.rewind();
        int pixelCount = width * height;
        int[] colors = new int[pixelCount];
        buf.asIntBuffer().get(colors);
        for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; i++) {
            int c = colors[i];
            colors[i] = (c & 0xff00ff00) | ((c & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) | ((c & 0x000000ff) << 16);
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
            bmp.recycle();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to write file " + filename, ioe);
        } finally {
            try {
                if (fos != null) fos.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe2) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to close file " + filename, ioe2);
            }
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Saved " + width + "x" + height + " frame as '" + filename + "'");
    }
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
E/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest: error while releasing muxer
                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't stop due to wrong state.
                                   at android.media.MediaMuxer.stop(MediaMuxer.java:231)
                                   at com.example.name.videoeditortest.ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.extractDecodeEditEncodeMux(ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java 434)
                                   at com.example.name.videoeditortest.ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.access$000(ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java:58)
                                   at com.example.name.videoeditortest.ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest$TestWrapper.run(ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java:171)
                                   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

If I comment `GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);` in the drawFrame the video is rendered correctly but with not bitmap. If I comment `GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTextureBitmapID);` in the drawFrame I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: glVertexAttribPointer maPosition: glError 1280
at com.example.name.videoeditortest.TextureRender.checkGlError(TextureRender.java:259)
at com.example.name.videoeditortest.TextureRender.drawFrame(TextureRender.java:111)
at com.example.name.videoeditortest.OutputSurface.drawImage(OutputSurface.java:252)
at com.example.name.videoeditortest.ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.doExtractDecodeEditEncodeMux(ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java:793)
at com.example.name.videoeditortest.ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.extractDecodeEditEncodeMux(ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java:341)
at com.example.name.videoeditortest.ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.access$000(ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java:58)
at com.example.name.videoeditortest.ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest$TestWrapper.run(ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java:171)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two things that seems wrong to me.

1. You are trying to bind everything at the same time, and hope that one call to `GLES20.glDrawArrays()` will draw everything.
2. You have only one shader, where you should have two : one for doing video texture rendering, and another for your bitmap layer rendering.

What you must know is that a frame can be draw by multiple call to `glDrawArrays`, each call will just paint a little part over previously drawn stuff (basically).

---

The first part of rendering a frame in your case should look to this :

```
# init

loadShaderForVideo()

loadShaderForBitmapLayer()

prepareYourArraysEtc()
```

...

```
#loop

GLClear()

updateVideoTexture()

drawFrame(){
   drawVideo()
   drawBitmap()
}
drawVideo(){

    bindYourActiveTextureToVideo()

    setYourVertexAttribAndUniform()

    GLES20.glDrawArrays()

}

drawBitmap() {

    bindYourActiveTextureToBitmap()

    setYourVertexAttribAndUniform() // This should be the same as above for video
    // Considering you want to draw above your video, consider activating the blending for transparency :

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays()

}
```

---

Concerning the shader, just take a look at these :

A common `Vertex Shader` for both :

```
public static final String vertexDefaultShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uVPMatrix;" +
                "uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;" + // uniform = input const
                "attribute vec3 aPosition;" +  // attribute = input property different for each vertex
                "attribute vec2 aTexCoordinate;" +
                "varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;" +// varying = output property different for each pixel

                "void main() {" +
                "vTexCoordinate = aTexCoordinate;" +
                "gl_Position = uVPMatrix * uModelMatrix * vec4(aPosition,1.0);" +
                "}";
```

Then a basic `fragment shader` ( for your bitmap 2D texture ) :

```
    public static final String fragmentDefaultShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform sampler2D uTexture;" +
                "varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;" +

                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTexCoordinate);" +
                "}";
```

Then a different version for video rendering :

```
    public static final String fragmentExternalShaderCode =
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;" +
                "varying vec2 vTexCoordinate;" +

                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTexCoordinate);" +
                "}";
```

Thus you will need two Programs, one with the defaultVertexShader + defaultFragmentShader and another with defaultVertexShader + fragmentExternalShaderCode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's really helpful. As you can you see I stated that I expect from the bounty winner to provide a functioning code. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes I saw your conditions. I'll see that deeper if I have a too much free time, but can't do more right now.

Comment: Can you please share full code? It will really helpful.

Comment: hey @ZiadHalabi would you share your updated code of this question!

Answer (score 0):

Buggy but works. Per J.Jacobs-VP, you need to use two programs and two shaders, one for video frame and the other for the bitmap.

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2013 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

var gles = 2

/**
 * Code for rendering a texture onto a surface using OpenGL ES 2.0.
 */

internal class TextureRender {

    /** Video Frame **/

    private val mTriangleVerticesData = floatArrayOf( // X, Y, Z, U, V
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0f, 0f, 1f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0f, 1f, 1f
    )

    private val mTriangleVertices: FloatBuffer
    private val mMVPMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private val mSTMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private var mProgram = 0
    var textureId = -12345
        private set
    private var muMVPMatrixHandle = 0
    private var muSTMatrixHandle = 0
    private var maPositionHandle = 0
    private var maTextureHandle = 0

    /** Bitmap Overlay **/

    private val mBitmapTriangleVerticesData = floatArrayOf( // X, Y, Z, U, V
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0f, 0f, 0f,
        1.0f, -1.0f, 0f, 1f, 0f,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 0f, 0f, 1f,
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0f, 1f, 1f
    )

    private val mBitmapTriangleVertices: FloatBuffer

    private var mBitmapProgram = 1
    private val mBitmapMVPMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private val mBitmapSTMatrix = FloatArray(16)
    private var mBitmapuMVPMatrixHandle = 0
    private var mBitmapuSTMatrixHandle = 0
    private var mBitmapaPositionHandle = 0
    private var mBitmapaTextureHandle = 0
    var bitmapTextureId = -12345
        private set

    fun drawFrame(st: SurfaceTexture, sourceWidth: Int, sourceHeight: Int, targetWidth: Int, targetHeight: Int, flipHorizontally: Boolean, flipVertically: Boolean) {

        if (gles == 2) {

            /** Draw Frame **/
            println("drawFrame")

            checkGlError("onDrawFrame start")
            st.getTransformMatrix(mSTMatrix)
            //GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
            GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT or GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
            GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram)

            checkGlError("glUseProgram")

            // original

            GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0)
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureId)

            // vertices

            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET)
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                maPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices
            )

            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maPosition")
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionHandle)

            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maPositionHandle")
            mTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET)
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                maTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mTriangleVertices
            )
            checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer maTextureHandle")
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureHandle)

            checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle")
            Matrix.setIdentityM(mMVPMatrix, 0)
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0)
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mSTMatrix, 0)

            GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)
            checkGlError("glDrawArrays")

            /** Draw Bitmap **/

            // bitmap

            // save to bitmap

            val bmp = savePixels(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight)

            // load texture from bitmap

            println("bmp: ${bmp?.width} ${bmp?.height}")

            if (bmp != null) {

                //val monochromeBmp = convertToBlackWhite(bmp)?.rotate(90f)
                var monochromeBmp = convertToBlackWhite(bmp)

                if (sourceHeight > sourceWidth) {
                    if (monochromeBmp != null) {
                        //monochromeBmp.rotate(90f)
                    }
                }

                println("monochromeBmp: ${monochromeBmp?.width} ${monochromeBmp?.height}")

                println("drawFrame")

                checkGlError("onDrawFrame start")
                st.getTransformMatrix(mBitmapSTMatrix)
                GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)
                GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT or GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
                GLES20.glUseProgram(mBitmapProgram)

                checkGlError("glUseProgram")

                // original

                GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE1)
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, bitmapTextureId)

                // vertices

                mBitmapTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET)
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                    mBitmapaPositionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                    TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mBitmapTriangleVertices
                )

                checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer mBitmapaPosition")
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mBitmapaPositionHandle)

                checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray mBitmapaPositionHandle")
                mBitmapTriangleVertices.position(TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET)
                GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                    mBitmapaTextureHandle, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                    TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES, mBitmapTriangleVertices
                )
                checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer mBitmapaTextureHandle")
                GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mBitmapaTextureHandle)

                checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray maTextureHandle")
                Matrix.setIdentityM(mBitmapMVPMatrix, 0)
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mBitmapuMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mBitmapMVPMatrix, 0)
                GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mBitmapuSTMatrixHandle, 1, false, mBitmapSTMatrix, 0)

                if (monochromeBmp != null) {

                    loadTexture(monochromeBmp)

                    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4)
                    checkGlError("glDrawArrays")

                }

            }

            // finish

            GLES20.glFinish()

        }

    }

    /**
     * Save Bitmap as Grayscale
     **/

    private fun convertToBlackWhite(bmp: Bitmap): Bitmap? {
        val width = bmp.width
        val height = bmp.height
        val pixels = IntArray(width * height)
        bmp.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)
        val alpha = 0xFF shl 24 // ?bitmap?24?
        for (i in 0 until height) {
            for (j in 0 until width) {
                var grey = pixels[width * i + j]
                val red = grey and 0x00FF0000 shr 16
                val green = grey and 0x0000FF00 shr 8
                val blue = grey and 0x000000FF
                grey = (red * 0.3 + green * 0.59 + blue * 0.11).toInt()
                grey = alpha or (grey shl 16) or (grey shl 8) or grey
                pixels[width * i + j] = grey
            }
        }
        val newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
        newBmp.setPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height)
        return newBmp
    }

    /**
     Rotate Bitmap
     */
    fun Bitmap.rotate(degrees: Float): Bitmap {
        val matrix = android.graphics.Matrix().apply { postRotate(degrees) }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(this, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, true)
    }

    /**
     * Save Texture as Bitmap
     **/

    private fun savePixels(x: Int, y: Int, w: Int, h: Int): Bitmap? {

        val b = IntArray(w * (y + h))
        val bt = IntArray(w * h)
        val ib: IntBuffer = IntBuffer.wrap(b)
        ib.position(0)
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, w, h, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, ib)
        var i = 0
        var k = 0
        while (i < h) {
            //remember, that OpenGL bitmap is incompatible with Android bitmap
            //and so, some correction need.
            for (j in 0 until w) {
                val pix = b[i * w + j]
                val pb = pix shr 16 and 0xff
                val pr = pix shl 16 and 0x00ff0000
                val pix1 = pix and -0xff0100 or pr or pb
                bt[(h - k - 1) * w + j] = pix1
            }
            i++
            k++
        }
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(bt, w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    }

    fun saveImage(finalBitmap: Bitmap) {

        val generator = Random()
        var n = 10000
        n = generator.nextInt(n)
        val fname = "Image-$n.jpg"
        val file = File(output(fname)!!.path!!)
        if (file.exists()) file.delete()
        try {
            val out = FileOutputStream(file)
            finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out)
            out.flush()
            out.close()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun output(fileName: String) : Uri? {

        val root = mainctx!!.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)

        val myDir = File("$root/Files/")

        if (!myDir.exists()) {

            Log.d("TAG", "$myDir doesn't exist")

            myDir.mkdirs()

        }

        try {

            val f = File(myDir, fileName)

            if (f.exists()) {

                //println("File Exists! Deleting")

                f.delete()

            }

            f.createNewFile()

            // file Uri

            //println("fileUri: $fileUri")

            return Uri.fromFile(f)

            // File Saved

        } catch (e: FileNotFoundException) {

            //println("FileNotFoundException")

            e.printStackTrace()

            return null

        } catch (e: IOException) {

            //println("IOException")

            e.printStackTrace()

            return null

        }

    }


    /**
     * Load Texture from Bitmap
     **/

    private fun loadTexture(bitmap: Bitmap) {

        println("loadTexture")

        // Bind to the texture in OpenGL

        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, bitmapTextureId)

        // Set filtering

        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST)
        GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST)

        // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.

        println("bitmap: ${bitmap.width} ${bitmap.height}")

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0)

        // check errors

        checkGlError("texImage2d");

        // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.

        bitmap.recycle()

    }

    /**
     * Initializes GL state.  Call this after the EGL surface has been created and made current.
     */

    fun surfaceCreated() {

        println("surfaceCreated")

        if (gles == 2) {

            // video shader

            mProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_SHADER)
            if (mProgram == 0) {
                throw RuntimeException("failed creating program")
            }
            maPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aPosition")
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition")
            if (maPositionHandle == -1) {
                throw RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition")
            }
            maTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "aTextureCoord")
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord")
            if (maTextureHandle == -1) {
                throw RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord")
            }
            muMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix")
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix")
            if (muMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix")
            }
            muSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uSTMatrix")
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix")
            if (muSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix")
            }
            val textures = IntArray(1)
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0)
            textureId = textures[0]
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, textureId)
            checkGlError("glBindTexture mTextureID")
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(
                GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST.toFloat()
            )
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(
                GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR.toFloat()
            )
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(
                GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
            )
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(
                GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
            )
            checkGlError("glTexParameter")

            // bitmap shader

            mBitmapProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, FRAGMENT_BITMAP_SHADER)
            if (mBitmapProgram == 0) {
                throw RuntimeException("failed creating program")
            }
            mBitmapaPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mBitmapProgram, "aPosition")
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aPosition")
            if (mBitmapaPositionHandle == -1) {
                throw RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aPosition")
            }
            mBitmapaTextureHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mBitmapProgram, "aTextureCoord")
            checkGlError("glGetAttribLocation aTextureCoord")
            if (mBitmapaTextureHandle == -1) {
                throw RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for aTextureCoord")
            }
            mBitmapuMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mBitmapProgram, "uMVPMatrix")
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uMVPMatrix")
            if (mBitmapuMVPMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uMVPMatrix")
            }
            mBitmapuSTMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mBitmapProgram, "uSTMatrix")
            checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation uSTMatrix")
            if (mBitmapuSTMatrixHandle == -1) {
                throw RuntimeException("Could not get attrib location for uSTMatrix")
            }
            val bmpTextures = IntArray(1)
            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, bmpTextures, 0)
            bitmapTextureId = textures[0]
            GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, bitmapTextureId)
            checkGlError("glBindTexture bitmapTextureId")
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(
                GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_NEAREST.toFloat()
            )
            GLES20.glTexParameterf(
                GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GLES20.GL_LINEAR.toFloat()
            )
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(
                GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
            )
            GLES20.glTexParameteri(
                GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
                GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
            )
            checkGlError("glTexParameter")

        }

    }

    /**
     * Replaces the fragment shader.
     */

    fun changeFragmentShader(fragmentShader: String) {

        if (gles == 2) {

            GLES20.glDeleteProgram(mProgram)
            mProgram = createProgram(VERTEX_SHADER, fragmentShader)
            if (mProgram == 0) {
                throw RuntimeException("failed creating program")
            }

        }

    }

    private fun loadShader(shaderType: Int, source: String): Int {

        if (gles == 2) {

            var shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(shaderType)
            checkGlError("glCreateShader type=$shaderType")
            GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, source)
            GLES20.glCompileShader(shader)
            val compiled = IntArray(1)
            GLES20.glGetShaderiv(shader, GLES20.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, compiled, 0)
            if (compiled[0] == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not compile shader $shaderType:")
                Log.e(TAG, " " + GLES20.glGetShaderInfoLog(shader))
                GLES20.glDeleteShader(shader)
                shader = 0
            }
            return shader

        }

    }

    private fun createProgram(vertexSource: String, fragmentSource: String): Int {

        if (gles == 2) {

            val vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexSource)
            if (vertexShader == 0) {
                return 0
            }
            val pixelShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentSource)
            if (pixelShader == 0) {
                return 0
            }
            var program = GLES20.glCreateProgram()
            checkGlError("glCreateProgram")
            if (program == 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not create program")
            }
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, vertexShader)
            checkGlError("glAttachShader")
            GLES20.glAttachShader(program, pixelShader)
            checkGlError("glAttachShader")
            GLES20.glLinkProgram(program)
            val linkStatus = IntArray(1)
            GLES20.glGetProgramiv(program, GLES20.GL_LINK_STATUS, linkStatus, 0)
            if (linkStatus[0] != GLES20.GL_TRUE) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not link program: ")
                Log.e(TAG, GLES20.glGetProgramInfoLog(program))
                GLES20.glDeleteProgram(program)
                program = 0
            }
            return program

        }

    }

    fun checkGlError(op: String) {

        if (gles == 2) {

            var error: Int
            while (GLES20.glGetError().also { error = it } != GLES20.GL_NO_ERROR) {
                Log.e(TAG, "$op: glError $error")
                throw RuntimeException("$op: glError $error")
            }

        }

    }

    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "TextureRender"
        private const val FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES = 4
        private const val TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_STRIDE_BYTES = 5 * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES
        private const val TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_POS_OFFSET = 0
        private const val TRIANGLE_VERTICES_DATA_UV_OFFSET = 3
        private const val VERTEX_SHADER = "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;\n" +
                "uniform mat4 uSTMatrix;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n" +
                "attribute vec4 aTextureCoord;\n" +
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * aPosition;\n" +
                "  vTextureCoord = (uSTMatrix * aTextureCoord).xy;\n" +
                "}\n"
        private const val FRAGMENT_SHADER = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;\n" +  // highp here doesn't seem to matter
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "}\n"
        private const val FRAGMENT_BITMAP_SHADER = "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
                "precision mediump float;\n" +  // highp here doesn't seem to matter
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +
                "uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n" +
                "void main() {\n" +
                "  gl_FragColor = texture2D(uTexture, vTextureCoord);\n" +
                "}\n"
    }

    init {
        mTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            mTriangleVerticesData.size * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES
        )
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer()
        mTriangleVertices.put(mTriangleVerticesData).position(0)
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0)


        mBitmapTriangleVertices = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            mBitmapTriangleVerticesData.size * FLOAT_SIZE_BYTES
        )
            .order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer()
        mBitmapTriangleVertices.put(mBitmapTriangleVerticesData).position(0)
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mBitmapSTMatrix, 0)
    }

}
```